# Using TIBDatabase to connect to a Firebird 2.1 database on Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, firebird

Is it possible to use Interbase components to connect to a Firebird 2.1 database?

I am migrating my software from delphi 7 to XE3 and I use IBX components wich seemed to me that would be updatable to Interbase components on XE3, but some awkward errors are happening.

I started a new project to isolate the problem, and tried to connect to my software database. The results follows.

1 - I can connect to the database using TIBDatabase normally

2 - TIBTable can list database tables normally

3 - TIBTable can fetch fields information normally

*4 - When I try to activate TIBTable I get the error message: "Dynamic SQL Error. SQL Error code -206. Column unknown. IBTable1. At Line 1, column 8". IBTable1 is the IBTable component name (???)

*5 - When I try to use a TIBSQL, I link it to the database and when I try to edit the SQL query Delphi dies.

Comment: Please expand on the troublesome SQL statements part.

Comment: There are no statements (not written by me) involved. As you can see the problem on item 4 is on a TIBTable e on item 5 it happens before I even have the chance to write any statement.

Comment: Looks like serious fookup for me. As TIBtable should by default query `select * from <tablename>` and the from error message it looks it uses `select ???, <component.name> ...`

Comment: Interbase components are never made to work with Firebird. Migrate to FIBPlus

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem a while back and while there are work arounds the best thing to do is to go through the pain and migrate to something else. Even if you get this problem solved you will keep running into minor problems until you make the change